# OnEdit on a specific Column to then trigger SendMail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a stock management system with Sheets.

I want it to notify by way of email, when an entry in Column D changes.

(Column D is a boolean determining if we will order equipment or not and has values of yes or no)

Right now, OnEdit is emailing me every time a cell is changed, I need it to only do it on column D.

Here's what I've written so far:

```
// script that will look send an email when an entry in 
Column D is amended.
//function onEdit(e) {
function onEdit(e) {
const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
const range = e.range;
const editedColumn = range.getColumn();

// Specify the column to act on
const targetColumn = 4; // Column D

if (editedColumn === targetColumn) {
// code to be executed when an edit is made in the specified 
column (D)
sendmail()

}
}
```

Expected that by declaring column D it would only report when that column changes

Comment: Why don't you do something with the received `e`vent? See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedite

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.value == "Yes") {
    sendmail()
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you Cooper



I am getting an error stating that 

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
onEdit @ Code.gs:6


Also - is there a way, that I can get it to ONLY trigger "sendmail" when column D has "Yes" in it? I imagine a simple IF statement but is there a "nicer" way

Comment: You must always supply and event object when you run this function without an onEdit trigger.